# JQuery: 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' build JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My Code is below. I am trying to build a json to pass a url which accept json string as

```
{
    "Item":{
        "Id":"e2b249d1",
        "Name":"aaaa"
    },
    "Status":1
}
```

my function :

```
var AddEditItem = function (itemid, itemname, status) {
    var itemdata = {
        "item": {
            "Id": itemid,
            "Name": itemname
        },
        "Status": status
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: url,
        data: itemdata,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {},
        error: function(response) {}
    });
};
```

I got error

> JQuery: 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation'

Any help?

Comment: how the server function look like?

Comment: You will need to confirm the parameter values passed into AddEditItem are simple values and not some complex HTML DOM elements etc. If you put `console.log (itemdata)` just before the ajax call what does it show?

Comment: How are you calling this function? `AddEditItem`

Comment: it is a wcf service. I send json as I wrote in question.

Comment: AddEditItem("cccc", "gu8765-ou", "1");

Answer (score 1):

you should serialize that object before sending to ajax

use `JSON.stringify()` for that

```
itemdata= JSON.stringify(itemdata);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: url,
data: itemdata,
dataType: "json",
success: function(response) {},
error: function(response) {}
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: itemdata= JSON.stringify(itemdata);

Comment: your example has no variables implicitly defined